# How to setup Azure Function Continuous Deployment using Enterprise Github?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, continuous-deployment, github-enterprise

Can someone confirm/deny that Azure Function Continuous Deployment does not support Enterprise Github?

When I select `Github` from the Deployment Center according to these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment#requirements-for-continuous-deployment), the authorization does not allow me to configure an Enterprise Github repo connection, only a Github.com connection.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also can not find the enterprise github repo after I create it:

[image]

To solve this, please go to the settings of your organization, and remove the third part access restriction:

[image]

Then go to the deployment center of your function app to re-authorize your github account:

[image]

At last, you will find the enterprise repo.