# Authorize gitHub enterprise for Azure function app (python)

Tags: azure, github, azure-functions

I want to authorize to GitHub Enterprise via my Azure function apps. In the deployment center, I can see options to 'Authorize' my azure function app to GitHub, however, when I am giving my GitHub enterprise credentials, the login page is saying it as invalid credentials.

I did cross-check, by directly logging into the git hub enterprise URL, and the credentials are working.

I want to know if I am missing anything.

**Screenshots:**

Below is the prompt for GitHub AuthZ

[image]

Here I provide my GitHub enterprise creds (showing fake creds in screenshots)

[image]

Login failed for the same creds.

[image]

Comment: I have received same issue when i entered wrong username / password, try to enter correct credentials.

Comment: @ManjunathRao, Did you try to login with Github credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did cross-check, by directly logging into the git hub enterprise URL, and the credentials are working.

AFAIK, you can authorize Azure Functions with GitHub. Try to login with your GitHub account credentials.

When I tried to login with my ***GitHub Enterprise credentials***, I was also getting the error as shown below:

[image]

*And with the same credentials I am able to login through browser.*

Later, I tried to login with my ***GitHub credentials***, and I could login without any issues:

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

[How to setup Azure Function Continuous Deployment using Enterprise Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718003/how-to-setup-azure-function-continuous-deployment-using-enterprise-github).